# Text centered over video in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

I have my container `div` that contain a video and a `div` with some text.

I would like that the text is above the video and in the central position, also when I resize browser window.

I realize this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TjjEP/18/), but I think is only a starting point.. how can I improve my code?

Here is the code.

```css
/**CSS**/

video {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}

#custom-message {
  position:relative;
  color: rgb(230, 200, 98);
  z-index:1;
  top: -200px;       
}
```

```html
<!--**HTML**-->

<div id="container" align="center">
  <video width="640" height="320" autoplay>
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
  <div id="custom-message">CENTERED TEXT ABOVE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you modify the HTML? Merely putting `#custom-message` above `video` in the HTML will work exactly as you intend (provided you remove the relative values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See snippet here:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TjjEP/20/)

```
var $vid = $('video','#container');
var $msg = $('#custom-message'); 
$msg.css({
    top:$vid.offset().top + (($vid.height()/2) - ($msg.height()/2)),
    left:$vid.offset().left + (($vid.width()/2) - ($msg.width()/2))
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, `z-index: -1` will screw things up in Firefox. Use this:

```
<div id="video-container">
// all the video stuff goes in here.
<a id="your-text"></a>
</div>

#video-container {
   text-align: center;
   height: 400px;//or whatever you want
   line-height:400px;//should be equal to the height
   position: ..
   z-index: 1;
}

#custom-message {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height:..;
    width:..;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Best way to do this is with JavaScript though. You need to use `z-index` no matter what, so position the video container relatively, the custom message absolute, but inside of the video container, and then simply use JavaScript to compute the `left` and `top` of the custom message. The bellow is the raw JavaScript(no library) way of doing things.

```
window.onload = funciton() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video-container');
    var customMessage = document.getElementById('custom-message');
    var customMessageTop = video.offsetHeight / 2 - customMessage.offsetHeight / 2;
    var customMessageLeft = video.offsetWidth / 2 - customMessage.offsetWidth  / 2;
    customMessage.style.left = customMessageLeft + 'px';
    customMessage.style.top = customMessageTop + 'px';
};
```

or if you are already using jQuery for your stuff.

```
$(function() {
    $('#customMessage').css({
        top: $('#video').height() / 2 - $('#customMessage').height() / 2,
        left: $('#video').width() / 2 - $('#customMessage').width() / 2
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

css:

```
video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}

#custom-message {
    position:relative;
    color: rgb(230, 200, 98);
    z-index:1;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;    
}​
```

html:

```
<div id="container" align="center">
     <div id="custom-message">CENTERED TEXT ABOVE</div>

    <video width="640" height="320" autoplay>
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>​
```